# Pivot table in Google sheets without importing data between sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have two sheets `sheet1` and `sheet2`. Without pulling all the data from `sheet2` into `sheet1`, how can I create pivot table in `sheet1`?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
*(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455901/pivot-table-in-google-sheets-without-importing-data-between-sheets/64456379?noredirect=1#comment113975530_64456379))*

I am afraid you cannot.
**Pivot only accepts references to ranges from within the same spreadsheet.**

**As a workaround** though, you could create the pivot table in one spreadsheet and then use `IMPORTRANGE` to refer to it in another spreadsheet.

In our example it would be

```
=IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx", "Sheet3!Q7:R13")
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

You need to choose the range from one sheet and create it in a cell in the other as shown in the following image

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marikamitsos. I meant from one google sheet to another one, not in different tabs in the same google sheet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought I was missing something :) Still. Please do check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Marikamitsos. I thought importrange can import the dataset from one google sheet to another. Can it import the pivot table as well? Your example looks like you're importing the dataset, not the pivot table. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: **You stand correct**. `IMPORTRANGE` can only import the dataset. As mentioned it is a workaround. Meaning ranges will be updated whenever the pivot changes. By giving it more space (eg. `Q7:T21`) you accommodate for possible future expansion of the table. Couple other workarounds would be to bring everything needed, into a hidden sheet or even use importrange in combination with query's pivoting clause ([see this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138313/117311))

Comment: Out of curiosity. Has any of the workarounds worked for you?

Comment: Thanks Marikamitsos for explaining in details. Actually I couldn't resolve what exactly I asked for, but imported the data in a different place. So one of the workarounds worked for me. Thank you for your help!